# Android. Change web service URLs between Beta and Live versions

Tags: android, url, beta

I have an Android application that connects to web services. Currently the Beta version in Google Play looks at web services on a test domain (for testing purposes only). I want to be able to convert this to a live version in Google Play for release. This will still contain the test web service urls.

Is there any way to dynamically specify the test url for the test version of the app and the live url for the live version of the app. Or alternatively is there any way to store the url externally so it can be changed on the fly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, on some server ...

Comment: Does the app have any way of identifying that it is a test or live version...
e.g.
if (getVersion() == "Test")
{ // use test url }
else if (getVersion() == "Live")
{ // use live url }

Comment: you will change the config file on the server? i don't get it ... you wana change it dynamically without new version of app or not? if not, then hard-code the uri ... if you are using gradle then it can be easly done with buildConfig

Comment: You do not understand my question.
I need a way to change the url as the app moves from beta to live, without creating a new apk. Hardcoding urls is not acceptable, they may change.

Comment: If I hardcoded the url, I would not be able to use the 'promote to' feature on Google Play.

Comment: so you want to know if the app can recognize on its own if it has been published as beta or release version?

Comment: Yes. I could then store in the strings.xml a testUrl and a liveUrl for the instances of the web services and select the correct one accordingly.
Even better to look this up externally on a server (as mentioned by Selvin) but the same kind of thing.

Comment: Does anybody know how the app can recognise on its own if it is a beta or release version?